# HTTP (only) access BigQuery InsertAll record formatting error

Tags: json, google-bigquery

Using: BigQuery [InsertAll](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll) over HTTP

(client libraries not an option - rules based case management system - using HTTP-only client)

With this Body:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "insertId": 123456,
      "json": {
        "my_object": {
          "json": {
            "name": "Alice",
            "age": 30
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "traceId": "test"
}
```

We get this response:

```
{
  "kind": "bigquery#tableDataInsertAllResponse",
  "insertErrors": [
    {
      "index": 0,
      "errors": [
        {
          "reason": "invalid",
          "location": "my_object",
          "debugInfo": "",
          "message": "This field: my_object is not a record."
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Where we have tried many variations of the syntax for my_object.

For this table structure:
[image: BigQuery sample table]
... how should the JSON object *within* the JSON body of the HTTP API call be structured?

NOTE: we can provide literal values for my_object (scalar strings, numerics, etc) - but this needs to be a JSON object.

NOTE: there are many descriptions of the client library syntax and object set up ... but client libraries are not an option in this environment.

Comment: If someone could trace the HTTP traffic that the client library is using in a context like this it would really help too!

Comment: I tried with the json data you shared and got the same error message. Is it possible for you to try with client [libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/json-data#sql)?

Comment: We cannot use client libraries because this context is a rules-based tech - and client libraries *could* be plugged in but no other API has required this - carrying all the cost for what could be/looks like purely (undocumented) syntax issue ...

Comment: Can't you directly add the key-value pairs for the "name" and "age" properties in my_object instead json inside my_object?

Comment: Hi @Aidanapword, It seems like  there is no direct way to insert full json data into json data type columns (BigQuery [InsertAll](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll) over HTTP) but you can achieve this by some workarounds.If you want this feature you can raise a feature request in [Issue Tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#feature_requests). If my answer or comment addresses your issue you can consider upvoting and accepting my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirements you consider the below workarounds:

**First workaround (using Client Libraries):**

Python code:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import json

client = bigquery.Client()
table_id = "my-project.my-dataset.my-table"

rows_to_insert = [
    {"my_object": json.dumps({'name':'uuu','no':98})}
]

errors = client.insert_rows_json(table_id, rows_to_insert)  
if errors == []:
    print("New rows have been added.")
else:
    print("Encountered errors while inserting rows: {}".format(errors))
```

For more information you can refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/json-data)

**Second workaround (using cloud function):**

You can consider using the google cloud function for your requirement. You can run the above code in the cloud function after a little modification.We can [trigger](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling) the Cloud function using http requests. We can send json data through http url and we can fetch that data in the cloud function then we can insert that into the bigquery table.

For more information you can refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/overview).

**Third workaround (using the escape characters and double quotes,BigQuery [InsertAll](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/insertAll)):**

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "insertId": "00000",
      "json": {
        "my_object": "{\"name\":\"jjrr\",\"age\":100}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

JSON data is represented as a string with the escape characters and double quotes.For more information you can refer to this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/json_simple/json_simple_escape_characters.htm) and [link2](https://medium.com/@learnednwhati/how-to-escape-special-characters-in-building-a-json-string-2b772d6d1194).

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: JSON "stringify" (in C# parlance) does enable the JSON to be written to BQ as a string - the Third Workaround - thank you for your contribution!